# Read User Info (User Id and Name) from access Token. (Facebook, Twitter, Google, Microsoft)

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth

I am developing a webapi, the request to webapi will contain the access token in header (social media authentication).

I now need to read the User Id and Name with this Access_token. I need this for Facebook, Twitter, Google and Microsoft.

Please let me know.

For Facebook, I have managed to get this done by using Facebook SDK.

```
var client = new FacebookClient(token);
dynamic me = client.Get("me");
```

This returns me

```
{
    name: "David Beckham",
    id: "123453465465654"
}
```

If there is any single way(using OAuth? or ) to fetch for all 4, would be more than happy.

Comment: sounds like you're going to have to google for examples on `Obtaining an Access Token` for each of the Entities since they are all different and use different API's if you have `1` working for `FaceBookClient` then google for how to call it for the remaining 3 that you need

Comment: I already have access token for all 4. I tried googling and couldnt find for Twitter, Microsoft and Google. Also I don't mind using a different one that can get the information for all 4.

Answer (score 0):

When the user logs in successfully, their username info is in the response object.

This is where the access token comes from, and it is also where the username can be retrieved.

[image]

This video discusses this, he also has videos on the same playlist for adding Google Login and Facebook login.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1VB6B-cGYo&t=3s

If you want to see other characteristics saved in the response object use:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(response));
```